# Geom_vline time's value

Tags: r

I'm trying to add vertical line that specify an X limit value. My data :

```
 meltk1=structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "number", class = "factor"), 
        value = c(0L, 85L, 65L, 35L, 28L, 124L), Hour = c("00:23:00", 
        "00:29:00", "00:53:00", "04:51:00", "05:08:00", "05:23:00"
        )), .Names = c("variable", "value", "Hour"), row.names = c(168L, 
    169L, 170L, 1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

`Hour` is the time specify the time when I measured the variable, with no date. The problem with `geom_vline`, as I see in few posts, that it require a date. Since, I've no need to have date's information. How can I use geom_vline without date ?

As follow the code that I'm trying to use, but do not work for simple date. Is there any other alternative of `as.POSIXct` ? This code work when `Hour` has this form `2017-08-15 07:32:00 CEST` and `POSIXct("2017-08-15 00:53:00")`. But I want just `Hour` as Time.

```
ggplot(meltk1, aes(x=Hour, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line(size=1) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("00:53:00"))), color = "black", linetype = "dashed")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code treats 'Hour' as a discrete variable and not time wouldn't you rather just pick an arbitrary date and work with dates?:

```
library(ggplot2)
meltk1=structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = "number", class = "factor"), 
        value = c(0L, 85L, 65L, 35L, 28L, 124L), Hour = c("00:23:00", 
        "00:29:00", "00:53:00", "04:51:00", "05:08:00", "05:23:00"
        )), .Names = c("variable", "value", "Hour"), row.names = c(168L, 
                                                               169L, 
170L, 1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")

meltk1$Hour <- as.POSIXct(paste("2017-01-01", meltk1$Hour, "CEST"))


ggplot(meltk1, aes(x=Hour, y = value, group = variable, colour = 
variable)) +
    geom_line(size=1) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:53:00 CEST")), color = "black", linetype = "dashed")
```

Alternatively if you must have a plot where time is not to scale:

```
library(ggplot2)
meltk1=structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "number", class = "factor"), 
        value = c(0L, 85L, 65L, 35L, 28L, 124L), Hour = c("00:23:00", 
        "00:29:00", "00:53:00", "04:51:00", "05:08:00", "05:23:00"
        )), .Names = c("variable", "value", "Hour"), row.names = c(168L, 
                                                                   169L, 170L, 1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")


ggplot(meltk1, aes(x=Hour, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line(size=1) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 3, color = "black", linetype = "dashed")
```